# Why does `Integral(a, b)` w.r.t. `IndexedBase(c)[d]` give `Integral(0, b)` and not just `0`?

Tags: python, sympy

When I integrate `sympy.Integral(a, b)` with regard to `c[d]`, i.e. with regard to `IndexedBase(c)[d]`, I get `Integral(0, b)` which is clearly just `0`, as `.doit()` will show.  Why is it shown as `Integral(0, b)` rather than `0`?

```
In [416]: (sympy.Integral(a, b)).diff(sympy.IndexedBase(c)[d])
Out[416]: 
⌠     
⎮ 0 db
⌡
```

Comment: Can you report it as a bug on github?

Comment: @FrancescoBonazzi [Done](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41834132/974555).  I wasn't sure if it was a bug or if there was a proper reason for it.

Comment: Wrong link. [Here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/12097) is the issue.